# RGraph bar labelsAbove in the center of Bar to avoid Webview cutting it

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview, xamarin.android, rgraph

I'm using a Webview in Xamarin to draw an RGraph.Bar.

The user can press a "+" button to manipulate the Graph then Graph is refreshed. The thing is for some reason the Webview is cutting off the labelsAbove the bars.
[image: shown here]

I was wondering if there's a chance to put labelsAbove in the center of the bar or at the beggining of it so it's not that obvious or... a solution to the WebView cutting the graph (Height)

Comment: Could you provide your code for us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to try:

1. Try increasing the `marginTop` property. Try setting it to 50 and see how that looks.
2. Try wrapping your canvas in a div and adding some `margin-top` to it:

```
<div style="margin-top: 50px; display: inline-block">
    <canvas id="cvs" width="700" height="300"></canvas>
</div>
```